# Intermediate value too large for data type

Tags: algorithm

this is my first question here so I apologize if I don't quite word this correctly.
To be honest, I'm not even sure how to phrase this, but here it goes.
If I'm trying to evaluate an expression which becomes very large before shrinking again, can the intermediate value exceed the maximum allowable for a given data type?
For example, let's say that a data type (call it dummyType) cannot exceed 100 (in my hypothetical language). Then if I have a variable named temp of type dummyType and say temp = (100 + 2) / 2. The final result of this expression is less then 100 (51), but it has to exceed 100 before it gets there (102).

EDIT: Maybe that wasn't the best example since it easy to rewrite it so that it doesn't exceed the limit. The actual problem has en expression where the last thing I do it take the square root. It's an expression of the form sqrt(a*b + c) so it isn't easily factored so I could take the roots of the component parts.
Sorry about that, like I said, I wasn't even sure how to ask the question when I started writing this.

Comment: Is this question just about the example? The usual tricks are to do something like `a + (b - a) / 2` or switch to unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, trying to solve some Programming Challenges.
I would suggest you do [100/2 + 2/2]. So it never exceeds the limit.

Comment: Good answer. However, that doesn't work in my real problem. I've edited my question to make it more realistic.

Comment: you could do ` sqrt(b+c/a) / sqrt(a)` in case a>0 of course .

Comment: Smart. Guess I've been out of school too long, I'm getting rusty on manipulating formula. I'm not trying to nitpick, just want to make sure I'm not THAT rusty, but wouldn't it be sqrt(b+c/a)*sqrt(a) though? Still only if a>0.

Comment: In general : `sqrt((a/abs(a))*b+c/abs(a))/sqrt(abs(a))` . Whatever the sign of 'a' is.